# Expected 'AS' In Cast If Then

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting the following error when attempting the following SQL Code

```
SELECT
    g.WeekNumber as [Week], f.FranchiseName as Opponent, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN g.Home = 1 THEN 'Home' ELSE 'Away' END) AS HomeAway,
    g.PointsFor, g.PointAgainst, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN g.Won = 1 THEN 'Win' ELSE 'Loss' END) AS Result
FROM
    dbo.Game g
LEFT JOIN dbo.Franchise f ON g.OpponentID = f.FranchiseID
```

Resulting error is `Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.`

Am I doing the If/Then wrong? I want to convert my `bit` columns to say "Yes" or "No" in my view

Comment: You don't need a cast. Just use the case statement.

Comment: Ima give you a kiss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAST is used to convert an expression from one datatype to other. No need of CAST in your query and if youn are using then it should be like this :

```
CAST(CASE WHEN g.Home = 1 THEN 'Home' ELSE 'Away' END AS VARCHAR(5)) AS HomeAway
```